# What is the behaviour when an array is passed to an if condition of a callback in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I saw a callback in a controller that looks something like this:

```
 before_action :do_stuff, if: [:condition_1?, :condition_2?], only: :show
```

What will be the behaviour of the if condition in this case? The Rails documentation only specifies passing a symbol or a Proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both conditions return `true` or values other than `false` and `nil` then `do_stuff` method will be invoked but only for `show` action

Comment: That worked, but could you explain how that works internally in `ActiveSupport::Callbacks`?